# how to loop array and display unique key X and concat value Y

Tags: php

So i need to loop an array and display unique key IdTransferFile and concat the reference.

with the code above i get this:

diff
Delete transfer file : 1, Reference : [46]

diff
Delete transfer file : 2, Reference : [46]

diff
same
same
Delete transfer file : 3, Reference : [464747]

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [IdTransferFile] => 1
            [Reference] => 46
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [IdTransferFile] => 2
            [Reference] => 46
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [IdTransferFile] => 3
            [Reference] => 46
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [IdTransferFile] => 3
            [Reference] => 47
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [IdTransferFile] => 3
            [Reference] => 47
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [IdTransferFile] => 4
            [Reference] => 47
        )

)

if ($item["IdTransferFile"] == $pastTransferFile) {
  echo "same" . "<br>";
  if ($item["Reference"] != $pastReference) {
    $referenceText .= $item["Reference"]
  }
} else {
  if ($pastTransferFile != 0) {
    echo("Delete transfer file : " . $pastTransferFile . ", Reference : [" . $pastReferenceText . "]"  . "<br><br><br><br>");
   }

    $pastReferenceText = $transferFileText = "";
    $transferFileText .= $item["IdTransferFile"];
    echo "diff" . "<br>";
 }

        $pastTransferFile = $item["IdTransferFile"];
        $pastReference = $item["Reference"];
        $pastReferenceText .= $pastReference;
```

I expect to represent the references deleted for each transfer:

Delete transfer file : 1, Reference : [46]

Delete transfer file : 2, Reference : [46]

Delete transfer file : 3, Reference : [46,47]

...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt at answering a question on SO, so this is probably not the cleverest way, but I'm fairly confident it gets the job done.

```
$items = array (
0 => array (
        'id' => 1,
        'ref' => 46
    ),
1 => array (
        'id' => 2,
        'ref' => 46
    ),
2 => array (
        'id' => 3,
        'ref' => 46
    ),
3 => array (
        'id' => 3,
        'ref' => 47
    ),
4 => array (
        'id' => 3,
        'ref' => 47
    ),
5 => array (
        'id' => 4,
        'ref' => 47
    )
);

// unique id array
$uIdArr = array();

// loop through items 
foreach($items as $item) {
    // pass ids to unique id array
    $uIdArr[] = $item['id'];
};

// trim unique id array (remove duplicates), and make the id the key
$uIdArr = array_unique($uIdArr);
$uIdArr = array_flip($uIdArr);
// create array to hold ref for each unique id 
$uIdArr = array_map(function() { return array(); }, $uIdArr);

// for each ref
foreach($items as $key => $item) {
    // pass ref to corrosponding id
    array_push($uIdArr[$item['id']], $item['ref']);
    // var_export($uIdArr[$item['id']]);
};

// loop through unique id array and output the desired outcome
foreach($uIdArr as $id => $ref) {
    // $refString = implode(", ",$ref);
    $refString = implode(", ",array_unique($ref));
    echo $output = "Delete transfer file : ".$id.", Reference : [".$refString."]\n";
};

// Output
// Delete transfer file : 1, Reference : [46]
// Delete transfer file : 2, Reference : [46]
// Delete transfer file : 3, Reference : [46,47]
// Delete transfer file : 4, Reference : [47]

// var_export($uIdArr);
```

I'm happy for any suggested improvements, thanks.

Comment: thanks but i found how to do it, but yes nice alternative

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help, but i found how to do it.
all in the same foreach.

thanks again and good night

```
foreach($marks as $k => $item) {

//deletes

if ($pastTransferFile == 0) {
 $pastReference = $item["Reference"];
 $pastTransferFile = $item["IdTransferFile"];    
} else {    
if ($item["IdTransferFile"] == $pastTransferFile) {

if ($item["Reference"] != $pastReferenceValue) {
 $pastReference .= $item["Reference"] . ", ";
 $pastReferenceValue = $item["Reference"];
}
$pastTransferFile = $item["IdTransferFile"];    
} else {

$text = "Delete transfer file : ".$pastTransferFile.", Reference : [".  $pastReference."]";    

echo (str_replace(", ]","]",$text));

$pastTransferFile = $item["IdTransferFile"];
$pastReference = $item["Reference"].", ";    
$pastReferenceValue = $item["Reference"];   
}

}

}
```